# JPA CriteriaBuilder - Expression <List>

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I have a simple `CriteriaQuery` where I pattern match a simple search `String` against field entires in a `Person` entity... e.g the `searchString` is always decorated with `%searchString%`

```
//using MetaModel
Expression<List<Records>> records = root.get(Person_.records);
Expression<String> param = builder.parameter(String.class);

//pseudo code(i think i need something like this here)
Predicate myPred = for all records (any record.FIELD LIKE searchString)

Path<Integer> status = root.get("status");

criteriaQuery.where(
    builder.or(
        builder.like(
            root.<String>get("name"), searchString
        ),
        builder.like(
            root.<String>get("second_name"), searchString
        )
        //pseuso code (i thin i need to check my predicate here?)
        builder.like(mypredicate)



    ),
    builder.equal(status,value)
);
```

The `Person` object can contain many `Record` objects. I would like to update my query above to include a similar 'like' pattern match for each applicable field (`String`) of each element of the List of `Record`s. I obtain the `Record`s like below:

```
//using MetaModel
Expression<List<Records>> records = root.get(Person_.records);
Expression<String> param = builder.parameter(String.class);
```

I have updated my code with pseudocode of what i 'think' i want.Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide some additional detail about the problem you are having, such as: more detail about what you are trying to achieve, along with what you are trying and specifics about how or why it is not working?

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for reply. Problem trying to solve:search all db entries matching the search string. This is fine when building the criteria to search on'basic fields' as above.I now want to extend the search to also include entries in the embedded Lissy of Record objects. For ex, if searching on 'tim' any person obj that had matching field in name or surname OR if any o the record objs had a matching field the person obj would be returned.

Comment: @SeanMickey Hi Sean, thanks for reply. Problem trying to solve:search all db entries matching the search string. This is fine when building the criteria to search on'basic fields' as above.I now want to extend the search to also include entries in the embedded lisr of Record objects. For ex, if searching on 'tim' any person obj that had matching field in name or surname OR if any of its record objs had a matching field the person obj would be returned.

Comment: @SeanMickey I have updated teh sample code with pseudo code of what i think i need... hope this helse explain it? Thanks for the reply...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell this is not possible using CriteriaQuery. I need to use a SQL query...
Here's how I did it...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24488081/1843591

Answer (score 3):

At least for jpa 2.1 it is possible. First declare a join between the 2 entities and then use the join created to get through the variable.

```
//using MetaModel
Expression<List<Records>> records = root.get(Person_.records);
Expression<String> param = builder.parameter(String.class);

SetJoin<Person, Record> joinRecord = root.joinSet("records", JoinType.INNER);

Path<Integer> status = root.get("status");

criteriaQuery.where(
    builder.or(
        builder.like(
            root.<String>get("name"), searchString
        ),
        builder.like(
            root.<String>get("second_name"), searchString
        ),            
        builder.like(
            joinRecord.<String>get("FIELD_NAME"), searchString
        )


    ),
    builder.equal(status,value)
);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, this format is helpful. I didn't know you could do that with generics

Comment: I was searching for hours to find a solution for using Expressions and criterias with joins (especially with @ManyToMany JPA join). Thank you very much despite this old question. :)

Comment: Thank you! The usage of the `Join` help me a lot in a related problem